# Can I calculate mean and median if the data does not follow a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, median

I have data that do not follow a normal distribution. The data looks like: [image: skewed data].

Can I calculate mean and median with such non-normal distributed data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The mean and median are purely descriptive and can be calculated for any sample, and they always have the same interpretation.

What you *cannot* do is calculate quantiles based on normal distribution assumptions, as in "95% of the data lie between the mean plus/minus two standard deviations".